# I need to add 30 days to a date as a constraint in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need to add 30 days to a Date Column and store that new date in a Due Date Column, as a constraint before populating the tables. I already created the tables. This is what I have so far:

```sql
UPDATE transactions
SET DueDatePayment = DATE_ADD (TransDate, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
Here I don't know what to add to make work.

ALTER TABLE transactions
ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK (ADDDATE ( transDate, INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

I have these two statements, both shows error.

Comment: `both shows error` what is the error message?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "as a constraint"? Do you want to add a constraint/check that the value of one date column is at least 30 days away of another? Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the space after DATE_ADD...

```
UPDATE transactions
SET DueDatePayment = DATE_ADD(TransDate, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
WHERE TransID = 100;

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. Oh Gosh semi colon and spaces will kill me hahaha. Thanks

Comment: MySQL is a bit temperamental that way; sometimes it matters, and sometimes it doesn't!